# Delay of keyboard strokes when using VBA

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, ms-office

When using my MacBook Air with VBA (Excel 2016) the keyboard input behaves strangely.  Some keys (not all though) need to be hit twice before the character appears. Only with VBA does this happen otherwise no problem at all.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

The problem is with certain keys and I'm not sure with only certain Macros. Certainly in many I've used.

Comment: Are they the same keys all the time, or different ones?  Is it with all macros in VBA or just a specific one? What version of macOS?  Have you engaged with Microsoft support?

Comment: The issue is only with certain keys, not all and yes with all the macros I have worked with, and no I have not engaged Microsoft support. Is it a VBA issue or a MAC issue?

Comment: It could be either, but being that it's a MS product, they probably have some insight and it's good to attack a problem from two vectors.  So, just to confirm, the problem exists with all VBA macros, not just one and the keys otherwise work in other applications.  This narrows it to a Microsoft/macOS issue (not macOS by itself) and something specific to VBA.  Just out of curiosity, have you tried a simple JavaScript (instead of VBA) macro to see if the keys fail there.  If they don't it's likely a bug with MS.